# Is there a way to check buttons automatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I've named all my buttons like Button1, Button2 ... I have 9 buttons named like these. I want my program to change the text of the buttons near it. For example: When Button3 is clicked, it should change Button4 to Button 9's texts to empty.

Comment: What is the question? Changing the button text? Finding the button by name?

Comment: Loop through the buttons in the container and examine the Button name property.  Show your code for more help.

Comment: Like I will enter a string and if the string matches to a button's name, it will change that button's text

Comment: Use the [Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection?view=net-5.0) collection. Ex: `Form1.Controls["Button9"].Text = "Hello";`

Comment: Another option is to put the buttons in an array. You can organize this array in whatever way makes the task easier.

Answer (score 2):

We can dynamically assign the click events of button for example using that:

```
using System.Linq;

private void FormTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Controls.OfType<Button>()
          .Where(b => b.Name.StartsWith("Button"))
          .ToList()
          .ForEach(b => b.Click += Button_Click);
}
```

We get all controls being type of button at the root level of the current form instance, filtered by the name matching the specified pattern, and we foreach on the resulting [evaluation](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-immediate-execution) of the LINQ [deferred](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-deferred-execution) query as a list to assign the event handler method.

If controls are for example in a panel:

```
MyPanel.Controls.OfType<Button>()...
```

Now we can dynamically change the text property using the tab index setted according to the expected result (`Button1` has `X`, `Button2` has `X+1`, and so on):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var button = sender as Button;
  if ( button == null ) return;
  button.Parent.Controls.OfType<Button>()
                        .Where(b => b.TabIndex > button.TabIndex)
                        .ToList()
                        .ForEach(b => b.Text = "");
}
```

If we need to search controls recursively in all the form or from a container having an inner hierarchy:

[How to toggle visibility in Windows Forms C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62743270/how-to-toggle-visibility-in-windows-forms-c-sharp/62743364#62743364)

[How to change BackColor of all my Panel in my Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58011018/how-to-change-backcolor-of-all-my-panel-in-my-form/58011504#58011504)

To use a different schema we also can use the predefined array, or list, of buttons solution suggested by @JohnnyMopp:

```
private void FormTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Buttons.Add(Button1);
  Buttons.Add(Button2);
  Buttons.Add(Button3);
  Buttons.Add(Button4);
  Buttons.ForEach(b => b.Click += Button_Click);
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var button = sender as Button;
  if ( button == null ) return;
  Buttons.Where(b => b.TabIndex > button.TabIndex)
         .ToList()
         .ForEach(b => b.Text = "");
}
```

Also instead of using `TabIndex`, we can use the `Tag` for condition source, or even the list order itself.